# ValueError not being caught

Tags: python, exception, valueerror

I'm having some trouble capturing the ValueError exception.

1. If I test an input with a string i.e. 'a' instead of providing an int number, then it throws a ValueError as expected. But then why does my exception not capture this and print "error, try again with an integer"?

I gave it 've' as I haven't used this variable yet. I didn't give 'e', as I've already used this for another exception.

2. If I instead try except (TypeError,ValueError): then why does this also not work?

Note that this code is just for me to practice handling exceptions, the content itself is not meaningful.

```
while not correct_input:
    distance_travelled = float(input("enter distance travelled in km: ")) #input enters strings, so you must convert to the datatype you want
    monetary_value = float(input("amount paid to cover distance: "))
    price_per_litre = 1.59
    try:
        fuel_consumed = monetary_value/price_per_litre
        if monetary_value/price_per_litre < 0:
            raise Exception #I can raise my own custom exception here
    except Exception as e:
        print("too small, try again")
    except ValueError as ve: #Catch our exception, and handle it properly. Ensure specific exceptions at the top, general at the bottom
        print("error, try again with an integer")
    else: #Runs code if try doesn't raise an exception
        print(fuel_consumed)
        correct_input = True
    finally: #Regardless of error or not, what you wish for it to do. i.e. close a file, close database etc
        continue
```

Thanks

Comment: `except Exception as e` catches all exceptions. None of the other `catch` blocks will ever be reached.

Comment: ```except Exception as e``` this ll get executed before ```ValueError``` exception

Comment: Also, dividing by a string raises `TypeError`, not `ValueError`.

Comment: Thanks - i removed the first exception, but still same issue hmmm.

correct_input = False
while not correct_input:
    distance_travelled = float(input("enter distance travelled in km: ")) 
    monetary_value = float(input("amount paid to cover distance: "))
    price_per_litre = 1.59
    try:
        fuel_consumed = monetary_value/price_per_litre
    except ValueError as e:  #(Even if i remove 'as e' same issue)
        print("error")
    else: #Runs code if try doesn't raise an exception
        print(fuel_consumed)
        correct_input = True
    finally: 
        continue

Comment: " raise Exception " inside your if-statement is causing the problem. Before even reaching the exception blocks, the Exception is raised inside the 'try' block.

Comment: @Ashish please don't put code in comments; there's no formatting and whitespace (which is *critical* in Python) is not preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`< 0` you ll only meet this condition when you ll enter negative values, please see if you want that or you want `< 1`. else the code is follwing.

```
correct_input = False
while not correct_input:
    try: # just check if you are getting integer/floating value here only
        distance_travelled = float(input("enter distance travelled in km: ")) #input enters strings, so you must convert to the datatype you want
        monetary_value = float(input("amount paid to cover distance: "))
    except:
        print('Only Integer and Floting point number')
    price_per_litre = 1.59
    try:
        fuel_consumed = monetary_value/price_per_litre
        if monetary_value/price_per_litre < 0: # I have a doubt if you really want 0 here. OR 1
            raise ValueError # raise value error when condition is met.
    except ValueError as ve:
        print('Too Small')

    else:
        print(fuel_consumed)
        correct_input = True
    finally:
        continue
```

Comment: Maybe add an explanation rather than just posting some code

Comment: @RandomDavis added.

Comment: Thank you both, much appreciated. This code does work well. And yes <1 is more meaningful.
Ok i see you basically split the issue with two Try/Except blocks. I presume the first except will capture all Errors: i.e. ValueError, NameError etc related to that first try.

@Davis, to add on what you were saying before, is that "except Exeption" is similar to "except:", capturing all exceptions for the Try.  Even if i custom raised the Exception?

 I appreciated breaking the problem as shivan did, it now flows, where he raised a ValueError.

Comment: Your welcome, please mark accepted.